# metro.config.js customization isn’t working

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I have to disable the minifier in metro.config.js, because if I build my application on iOS devices it doesn't work properly.

The development build is ok, but after I upload it to TestFlight it keeps crashing, and I can't think of anything other than the minification.

The bundling just ignores my modifications in metro.config.js, if I add anything to it, it just skips it.

The following message appears in the terminal: **"Metro skipped: Project metro.config.js does not match prebuild template."**

The default metro.config.js is the following (generated by: **npx expo customize metro.config.js** ):

```
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

module.exports = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
```

This works flawlessly. But if i change it to this:

```
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

module.exports = config;
```

Then it skips the whole metro config.
Do you have any idea, why this happens?

Thanks for your help!

```
"dependencies": {
    "**@expo/metro-config": "^0.5.2**",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.4.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.3.6",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.2",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.6",
    "**expo": "~46.0.19**",
    "expo-av": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-device": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~14.1.0",
    "expo-linking": "~3.2.2",
    "expo-localization": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-location": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.16.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-task-manager": "~10.3.0",
    "i18n-js": "^4.2.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "**react-native": "0.69.6**",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.0",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "0.31.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.24",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.1.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-timer-hook": "^3.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.3",
    "use-debounce": "^8.0.4",
    "use-elapsed-time": "^3.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0"
  },
```

I have tried to solve this issue based on the official documentation (https://docs.expo.dev/guides/customizing-metro/), but no modification can be accepted. The bundling process always skips the custom file.

I have already tried a lot of workaround, that I found on StackOverflow and Github.